# Tango SDK Marker Detection (Release May 2017 Hopak): only 4 bit in AR tags?

Tags: google-project-tango

with the marker detection example (https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_marker_detection_example) I tried to detect AR Tags with id's higher than 16.

For that, I generated Alvar markers using http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar. (I have read these tags are Alvar in a comment in the google example source code). Is the SDK fixed to detect maximum only 16 ids (4bits)? If yes Does someone know if this will change in the future?

I am not interested in QR codes, since they don't seem to be robustly detected from perspective angles.

Comment: I have another question, did you try multiple marker with different sizes?