# Project Tango how to register new AR Marker

Tags: google-project-tango

i'm trying to build marker tracking AR app
is there a way to register new markers beside those that provided in the example?

Comment: Am also trying to do this.
QR Codes are supported, so in theory you can use any QR marker you like?  The marker detection example would I guess need to be changed from MarkerType.ARTAG to MarkerType.QRCODE.

For the other default (ALVAR) markers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984789/tango-sdk-marker-detection-release-may-2017-hopak-only-4-bit-in-ar-tags I didn't get any further than that guy.