# 3D AR Markers with Project Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, google-project-tango

I'm working on a project for an exhibition where an AR scene is supposed to be layered on top of a 3D printed object. Visitors will be given a device with the application pre-installed. Various objects should be seen around / on top of the exhibit, so the precision of tracking is quite important.

We're using Unity to render the scene, this is not something that can be changed as we're already well into development. However, we're somewhat flexible on the technology we use to recognize the 3D object to position the AR camera.

So far we've been using Vuforia. The 3D target feature didn't scan our object very well, so we're resorting to printing 2D markers and placing them on the table that the exhibit sits on. The tracking is precise enough, the downside is that the scene disappears whenever the marker is lost, e.g. when the user tries to get a closer look at something.

Now we've recently gotten our hands on a Lenovo Phab 2 pro and are trying to figure out if Tango can improve on this solution. If I understand correctly, the advantage of Tango is that we can use its internal sensors and motion tracking to estimate its trajectory, so even when the marker is lost it will continue to render the scene very accurately, and then do some drift correction once the marker is reacquired. Unfortunately, I can't find any tutorials on how to localize the marker in the first place.

Has anyone used Tango for 3D marker tracking before? I had a look at the Area Learning example included in the Unity plugin, by letting it scan our exhibit and table in a mostly featureless room. It does recognize the object in the correct orientation even when it is moved to a different location, however the scene it always off by a few centimeters, which is not precise enough for our purposes. There is also a 2D marker detection API for Tango, but it looks like it only works with QR codes or AR tags (like [this one](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/data/images/HIRO.jpg)), not arbitrary images like Vuforia.

Is what we're trying to achieve possible with Tango? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: There should be a demo scene in Unity Tango package for what you are after. Basically, it scans for marker and once found, it sets the marker tracking off and use the SLAM tech instead. Can't tell you the name of the scene but it is there.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `Extended Tracking` in Vuforia?

Comment: That won't do as good as Tango though.

Comment: Of course not, Tango is the best, however I assume they want other people to download their application, and not everyone has a Tango/ARCore enabled device in their pocket.

Comment: We don't need people to download the application, we will provide the devices at the exhibition. We already have 10 Lenovo Phab 2 pro phones available, which as far as I know are the only ones currently supporting Tango. However, I will check out Extended Tracking.

Thanks for your suggestion Everts, I will look through the Tango examples again.

Comment: The marker detections example in the Unity Tango package uses those ugly blocky AR tags. Do you know if it's possible to use arbitrary images? Also I can't seem to find any documentation on the marker detection anywhere...

Comment: One more question.. how do you place your 3D objects in your scene? If they are placed manually into a scene in Unity, it can be hard and sometimes misleading getting them positioned correctly. If your tango user clicks a plane and it dynamically makes something appear there, you don't see this issue. But when your space and Augmented object locations are pre-known, you need to find where in Unity space the Table is. I ended up having 3D mesh extraction running when I scanned the area, and imported that model into Unity. I could then use that model to align my virtual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Option A) Sticking with Vuforia.
As Hristo points out, Your marker loss problem should be fixable with [Extended Tracking](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking).  This sounds definitely worth testing.

Option B) Tango
Tango doesn't natively support other markers than the ARTags and QRCodes.

It also doesn't support the Area Learnt scene moving (much).  If your 3DPrinted objects stayed stationary you could scan an ADF and should have good quality tracking.  If all the objects stay still you should have a little but not too much drift.

However, if you are moving those 3D Printed objects, it will definitely throw that tracking off.  So moving objects shouldn't be part of the scanned scene.
You could make an ADF Scan without the 3D objects present to track the users position, and then track the 3D printed objects with ARMarkers using Tangos ARMarker detection.   (unsure - is that what you tried already?) .  If that approach doesn't work, I think your only Tango option is to add more features/lighting etc.. to the space to make the tracking more solid.

Overall, Natural Feature tracking by Vuforia (or Marker tracking for robustness) sounds more suited to what I think your project is doing, as users will mostly be looking at the ARTag/NFT objects.  However, if it's robustness is not up to scratch, Tango could provide a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The 3D printed target is static, however we do not have access to the venue ahead of time and there will be people moving around in the background - so the only thing we can scan is the object itself and the table it sits on. Even when drawing high contrast shapes on the table to improve feature detection, the localization with Area Learning is always off by a few centimeters, which does not suffice for our needs.

Extended Tracking in Vuforia works well with rotations, but does not handle translation of the device very well.

Comment: Do you know what markers Tango actually supports? I thought it just needed a black border with a non-rotation-invariant design inside, but it seems even more limited than that. The example includes 16 Alvar tags with no instruction of how to add others. The readme also specifically asks to make sure that the marker is exactly 14cm on each side, and I got significantly reduced quality of tracking when scaling it down. We can live with the less-than-aesthetic designs, but size is an issue. I may need to combine Vuforia's marker detection with Tango's motion detection somehow.

Comment: I believe others have tried and failed to add more Alvar markers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984789/tango-sdk-marker-detection-release-may-2017-hopak-only-4-bit-in-ar-tags you should be able to have any number of QR codes but their quality of tracking will be worse than Alvar style tags..

Comment: @MiriamTschanen Maybe you could show a perfect example(video) of how the tracking should look like for your app. The so called jitters can be dealt with in Vuforia using some simple math, if that is the problem.