# Is there an "Target.position" funcion for recognizing the distance between user and AR target?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, target, vuforia

How can I determine the user's relative position to an AR target? If there is any function for this, I need to add it to an Unity script.

This forum ([3D AR Markers with Project Tango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753314/3d-ar-markers-with-project-tango)) seems to suit a project of mine. I work at the science museum and I also want visitors to interact with the exhibition. Vuforia Object3DScanner had no solid build and recognition, so I use a 2D marker, as users will always be facing the experiment, never inside or behind it.
However, my exposure is not static, as it is a pendulum in motion. My AR projection must overlay the pendulum with a velocity vector and indicate its velocity. So getting the target position is important, because at the center of the movement the speed is maximum and at its extremes, minimum. I made a scheme to clarify my situation: [image: diagram of object being different distance from user with phone]

Comment: You can try to find the distance between the gameObject and AR camera through Vector3.Distance(); this will give you the distance value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Vector3.Distance({marker pos in world coodrinates}, {ar camera pos in world coordinates})`. 
For ArCore/ArKit (also for other but didn't checked all plugins) - distance calculating in meters, e.g. 1 unity distance unit = 1 real world meter.